# Need to remove an item from array based on condition in groovy

Tags: arrays, jenkins, groovy

I am able to fetch the subscription id and name from azure cli. Need to remove the subscriptions which has a particular string in their names. How to achieve this in groovy?

My code is as below

```
az account list --query '[].{name:name,id:id}
```

It returns the below values

```
    [
      {
        "id": "66666666666666",
        "name": "sub-demo-1"
      },
      {
        "id": "22222222222222",
        "name": "sub-demo-2"
      },
      {
        "id": "000000000000000",
        "name": "sub-prod-1"
      },
      {
        "id": "888888888888888",
        "name": "sub-prod-2"
      }
]
```

I need to remove all the subscriptions which has the name demo in it. Secondly it should save only the subscription ids to another array after removing the unwanted items.

I want the below output

```
[
000000000000000,
888888888888888
]
```

Comment: It's a command line - not a code. Show how you are at least assigning output into a variable and parsing it...

Comment: Once you show us how you assign the output to a variable I will post an answer that separates the correct IDs into a separate array.

Comment: As I mentioned in your other question which is extremely similar, and the previous comment, you are just running a command, which is not the same as getting the result into a variable. You are most likely to get it into a variable as a string, and then you start from there. The way you have initialised it above is completely wrong and you would never get it like that from a command into a variable.
Perhaps you need to get it as a text with a command similar to this one:
`def AccountList= sh(returnStdout: true, script: "az account list --query '[].{name:name,id:id}").trim()`